# Can "System.Math.Cos" return a (float)?

Tags: c#, .net, math, floating-point, double

In C# it bugs me how there is no "Math.Cos" function that returns a float. A double is the only value you can get back thus forcing you to cast it to a float.
Like so:
`float val = (float)Math.Cos(someVal);`

I need to use floats because i'm doing stuff in Direct3D which strictly uses floats.
Floats are much more common in the graphics world(as it stands now) because they are 32bit.

Is there any functionality within C# I can use that would simply just process floats like C++ can do??

I do not want to wrap any C++ stuff because this needs to run on XNA & Linux for OpenGL.

**NOTE**: It would nice to have code that did not cast a double to a float.

Comment: You could overload math.cos() with your own version that just returns a cast version.

Comment: While Direct3D requires floats, it's still better to work with double until you have to convert as it avoids most (but not all) rounding error problems.

Comment: @ChrisF - this really isn't true with games. The rounding is rarely an issue or can be dealt with by clamping, and the perf savings of avoiding Double is significant.

Comment: @codekaizen - I did work for a while in 3D graphics (not directly games though) and while floats were usually OK it was getting increasingly evident that we needed double for the worlds we were generating. I assumed that things had moved on from there.

Comment: You can't overload `Math.Cos` since you can't edit the Math class. You just can define a function in your own class.

Comment: @ChrisF - things are moving to Double, but it's slow. The current gen of GPUs are the first to support it with any reasonable performance.

Comment: I'm still trying to get over the fact that an allegedly modern language lacks a single-precision math library.

Comment: @codekaizen - it's moving a lot slower than I expected then (I moved out of 3D in 2005).

Comment: @ChrisF In 3D things will never move to double, and for a good reason. It is and will always be slower than float on optimized architectures like GPUs and will take twice as much memory, cache and bandwidth to operate on it. The move in opposite direction is more likely. GPUs often internally operate on 24 or even 16 bit floats and shading languages have special keywords to denote the lowest precision you can put up with. The only reason to use doubles is where your problem domain absolutely requires it, but this is rare in 3D.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without going into some in-depth math, you will not be able to write your own *accurate* Cos function. Here is a suggestion though using extension method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float cos = Math.Cos(.25d).ToFloat();

        Console.WriteLine("cos(.25d) = {0}", cos);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class MathExtensions
{
    public static float ToFloat(this double value)
    {
        return (float)value;
    }
}
```

This is another way using `Func<T, TResult>` and creating your own `MathF` static class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("cos(.25d) = {0}", MathF.Cos(.25d));
        Console.WriteLine("sin(.25d) = {0}", MathF.Sin(.25d));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public static class MathF
{
    public static Func<double, float> Cos = angleR => (float)Math.Cos(angleR);
    public static Func<double, float> Sin = angleR => (float)Math.Sin(angleR);
}
```

As others have pointed out, the Func delegates will be slower as zezba confirmed in his test code (I didn't know that the delegates would be that much slower). The quickest is the direct cast to float. The middle ground would be simple static method calls in the MathF static class.

Comment: Cos() is not a good name for a convert-to-single-precision extension function.

Comment: Why would you ever write `static Func<double, float> Cos = angleR => ...` instead of `static float Cos(double angleR) { ... }`?

Comment: Thankx so much for that great code. I didnt know about either of those methods and will be archiving them for later use. If you know of any way you don't have to cast that would be cool, but I doubt there is without wrapping c++.

Comment: I don't like your implementation of `MathF`. The idea of defining a `MathF` class is good. But using delegates here is stupid(yours aren't even readonly fields). Delegates just throw away performance here and make the code harder to understand since for example the documentation will list them as static fields instead of static methods. And I think the functions should take float instead of double. `float Cos(float angle){return (float)Math.Cos(angle);}`

Answer (score 13):

**Starting with .NET Core 2.0 (.NET Standard 2.1) (C# 8.0) and upper** this is possible thing as built-in function.

You can just use `MathF` class with built-in constants or functions working with `float` type.

Example:

```cs
float cos = MathF.Cos(MathF.PI);
```

For further information see [documentation on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.mathf?view=netcore-3.0) about `MathF` type.

Answer (score 5):

Ok so I ran some benchmarks to see what method was the fastest after reading "dboarman" reply. Sadly it seams there is no way to do it without casting using strictly c# & the fastest method is to just cast on spot, so because I care about speed as its mostly for games ill be sticking with the old cast method.

These tests were compiled using the following specs::

```
C# .NET 4.0
ConsoleApplication - Release - Optimized code - x64
4gb ram, 2.4ghz AMD_X2_DualCore 4600 CPU, running Windows7 Ultimate.
```

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Start
    Console.Write("Hit Enter to Start\n");
    Console.ReadLine();
    long num = 100;
    long mil = 0;
    float val = 0.01f;
    Stopwatch startTime = new Stopwatch();

    //Run
    for(long i = 0; i != num; ++i)
    {
        startTime.Restart();
        for(uint i2 = 0; i2 != 1000000; ++i2) val = (float)System.Math.Cos(val);// 48 Milliseconds
        //for(uint i2 = 0; i2 != 1000000; ++i2) val = System.Math.Cos(val).ToFloat();// 53 Milliseconds
        //for(uint i2 = 0; i2 != 1000000; ++i2) val = MathF2.Cos(val);// 59 Milliseconds
        //for(uint i2 = 0; i2 != 1000000; ++i2) val = MathF.Cos(val);// 63 Milliseconds
        startTime.Stop();
        mil += startTime.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    //End
    mil /= num;

    //Print
    Console.Write("Milliseconds = "+mil.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Here is the base math code for the tests::

```
public static class MathF
{
    public static Func<double, float> Cos = angleR => (float)System.Math.Cos(angleR);
    public static Func<double, float> Sin = angleR => (float)System.Math.Sin(angleR);
}

public static class MathF2
{
    public static float Cos(float pValue) {return (float)System.Math.Cos(pValue);}
}

public static class MathExtensions
{
    public static float ToFloat(this double value)
    {
        return (float)value;
    }
}
```

Comment: so if I read your test code correctly, time to complete 1 million casts with the standard cast method is 48ms? Nice job on the tests. I honestly didn't realize how much slower the Func delegates would be.

Comment: Yes you are correct, 1 million casts would complete in 48ms. I repeat the test 100 times then get the average & print the result.

Answer (score 4):

I would create a MathCommonMethods class with methods that would convert all of the frequently used return types to floats in leiu of doubles. This will save you some typing in the long run.

As far as there being an existing function that returns the value as a float, I've not heard of one.

You should also be careful too when casting not to lose precision, if precision is important to your application.

Comment: "Overload" means defining a group of methods with the same name in one class. If you're talking about adding a method to a different class, that's not overloading. It's just defining a method.

Comment: I had meant a derived class, to my understanding that's still considered an overload. Good catch though, my initial answer wasn't clear on that.

Comment: `System.Math` is a static class. You can't derive from it.

Comment: In that case, overload is not the correct term. :) Thanks again.

Comment: Well, you can pseudo-overload a static method on a type you don't own with extension methods. As far as intellisense is concerned (in VS), it looks like an overload has been added to the type.

Comment: @x0n How do you add static methods with extension methods? I think that extension methods can add only instance methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid casting, you'll need a different implementation. If you are doing cross-platform, you can create a platform abstraction layer where you can put different implementations based on the platform. This will help with performance. If perf isn't an issue (is this ever the case with games), then creating a utility function and performing the casting there is a good solution.

Comment: I had thought about doing that & that is a good idea. But I don't want to over complicate things. Although I think I may try that & see what speed improvements I get from it. Would be nice for PC, Mac & Linux, but would not work on XNA on the XBOX or Phone7.